gpio sysfs interface initialize pin high voltage
I am facing stupid problem. LED is on when pin is low. I need to get the pin as output with level high (LED physically turned off).

If I export and set direction to out, LED gets on, and value is read as 0.
If I export, write 1 to active_low, and then set direction to out, LED gets on, and value is read as 1.

But I can't write value until I set direction to output. Any ideas?
I have control over the device tree, therefore the suggestion to pre-configure the behavior of the unused gpio pin will be very welcome.
Update: special thanks to Andriy and sawdust for comments. I decided to design my own kernel module/driver, the bonus is I have put advanced functionality in, which would appear in user space anyway.

So, what prevents you from using leds-gpio driver, which can be configured directly in the device tree?

@0andriy I am not sure but if I use this device (put the gpio into this device type domain)  kernel hijacks the gpio and application able to use it no more.

To "pre-configure the behavior of the unused gpio pin" (a) from power on, you could try to use a pull-up resistor, or (b) before Linux, in U-Boot (or whatever you're using to load the kernel) configure the pin.

Application needs to be amended to use LED ABI instead of must-not-use GPIO sysfs one.
